# AWK how to read a line from file and get some value using substring

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I am new to AWK.
Can you please let me know how to read a line from file using awk? How can I get a value using substring function from read line and store it into a variable? For example here is the data set:

```
01 001   410070300186169                 359829047319420
01 002   410070234186169                 359829043245420
01 001   410070234186169                 359829047319420
```

I want to check if at position 4 to 6 , value is "001" then write the data in file file_1 and if the value is "002" then write the data in file file_2.

Comment: We can give vague answers at best to vague questions. Can you provide at least specific examples?

Comment: Thanks for your valuable input. A example data is added to the questioin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go; you can put this all on one line, but I've broken it down into multiple for readability:

```
awk '$2=="001" {print > "file_1"}
     $2=="002" {print > "file_2"}' input_file
```

**Explanation:**

- `awk` separates each line into fields using spaces and tabs as delimiters by default, so for each line read, values in your 2nd column will be saved in `$2`
- `$2=="001" {print > "file_1"}`: if `$2` is `001`, print the entire line into `file_1`
- `$2=="002" {print > "file_2"}`: likewise for `002`

Comment: Dear Sanoson, if I have to compare $2 value with some list contained in other or in db then how to do ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do all that in awk 1 liner like this:

```
awk '$2 == "001" {print > "file_1"} $2 == "002" {print > "file_2"}' infile
```

Comment: Thank you Anu for your reply. But you code does not take care about specific location. like from position 4 to 6

Comment: @QMG what is the error that you are seeing? His solution works based on the input format you specified in your example.

Comment: @QMG It is much better to compare input data using separate fields this way rather than substring from position 4 to 6 which is highly unreliable if somebody puts one extra space before 2nd field.

Answer (score 0):

You can read into $0 with

```
getline <file
```

then you can use

```
 substr($0, 1 , 5)
```

to get a substring of $0 starting at index 1 with length 5